# PropertyInfo GetValue and Expression Cache GetValue

Tags: c#

I have implemented PropertyInfo GetValue and Expression Cache GetValue by Logic from [Reflection vs. compiled expressions vs. delegates - Performance comparison](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2012/2/4/reflection-vs-compiled-expressions-vs-delegates-performance-comparison),but I'm sure that there are better ways to do every thing that I did. I would appreciate any feedback on this code, which does work according to spec:

#### MyLogic

> - Asynchronous nonblocking, which does not block thread when adding a Cache
> - Dictionary Key use propertyInfo GetHash()
> - if dictionary cache containskey then use compiler expression function else use Reflection GetValue

#### My Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class TestService
{
    private static Dictionary<int, object> ExpressionCache = new Dictionary<int, object>();

    public IEnumerable<string> Execute<T>(IEnumerable<T> enums)
    {
        var expressionCache = (enums);
        var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (var e in enums)
        {
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                var func = GetOrAddExpressionCache<T>(p);
                var value = string.Empty;
                if (func == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Use Reflection");
                    value = p.GetValue(e).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Use Expression");
                    value = func(e);
                }
                yield return value;
            }
        }
    }

    private Func<T, string> GetOrAddExpressionCache<T>(PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        var key = prop.GetHashCode();
        if (ExpressionCache.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            var func = ExpressionCache[key] as Func<T, string>;
            return func;
        }else{
            Task.Run(()=>AddExpressionCacheAsync<T>(prop));
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Asynchronous nonblocking, which does not block a thread when adding a Cache
    private async Task AddExpressionCacheAsync<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var key = propertyInfo.GetHashCode();
        if (!ExpressionCache.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            var func = GetValueGetter<T>(propertyInfo);
            ExpressionCache.Add(key, func);
        }
        await Task.Yield();
    }

    private static Func<T, string> GetValueGetter<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var instance = Expression.Parameter(propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
        var property = Expression.Property(instance, propertyInfo);
        var toString = Expression.Call(property, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(toString, instance).Compile();
    }
}
```

#### Demo

```
class Program{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        var data = new[] { new { Name = "Henry", Age = 25 } };
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var service = new TestService();
            var result = service.Execute(data).ToArray();
        }
    }
}

/* Console :
        Use Reflection
        Use Reflection
        Use Expression
        Use Expression
*/
```

Comment: Making a method `async` without `await` doesn't make it automagically asynchronous - your assumptions are wrong so the code is not working as you think it is.

Comment: thanks @t3chb0t , i read doc about async without await now.

Comment: I read this page [task parallel library - Using async without await in C#? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805887/using-async-without-await-in-c),it looks like `await Task.Run` is better. @t3chb0t

Comment: Why should `AddExpressionCacheAsync` be asynchronous anyway? It results in repeated (wasted) lambda-compilation work and unhandled task exceptions...

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I want to avoid expression first compile time then blocked thread

Comment: But the way you've implemented it causes multiple compilations for the same lambda, and you could run into obscure bugs because `Dictionary` is not thread-safe. Did you do this because you think it's too slow, or because you actually profiled it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problems

- Both the reflection and expression-based approach fail to take `null` values into account (`NullReferenceException`).
- They also fail to take types with indexers into account (`TargetParameterCountException`).
- Hash-codes are not unique identifiers. Different properties (and objects in general) can have the same hash code - that just means that they *might* be equal. Use `prop.MetadataToken` in combination with the module they're declared in (`prop.Module.ModuleVersionId`).
- Compiling expressions asynchronously makes this a lot more complex than it needs to be, and that complexity is not properly taken care of:

  - There's no guarantee that compilation will be finished when the next object is processed. This can result in multiple compilations for the same property. That's a waste of work.
  - The results of these compilations are added to a `Dictionary`, which is not thread-safe. In the best case, adding a key that already exists will throw an exception. In the worst case, the dictionary's internal state will become corrupted.
  - Those exceptions are not being caught. Before .NET Framework 4.5, that would've caused a crash, and in 4.5 and higher it may still do so, depending on certain settings.

#### Other improvements

- Why does `Execute` take a sequence of items, instead of a single item? Flattening results is easy (`data.SelectMany(service.Execute)`), 'unflattening' is not - the caller would have to figure out the number of properties, and you'd have to write a method to split up a single sequence into sub-sequences.
- Instead of doing `ExpressionCache.ContainsKey(key)`, followed by `ExpressionCache[key]`, use `TryGetValue`. This lets you check the presence of a key and get its associated value with a single lookup.
- There's no point in making `AddExpressionCacheAsync` `async`. It's not doing any asynchronous work (that `await Task.Yield()` is useless). You're already calling this method from within a `Task.Run` call, so it'll be executed asynchronously anyway.
- In `GetValueGetter`, use `nameof(object.ToString)` instead of `"ToString"`.

#### Readability issues

- Some names are not very descriptive: `Execute` -> `GetPropertyValues`, `enums` -> `items`, `func` -> `compiledExpression`, `GetValueGetter` -> `CompileGetValueExpression`.
- There are several abbreviations that do not improve readability: `e` -> `item`, `props` -> `properties`, `p` -> `property`.